# how to compile Lua 5.3.5 shared library?

Tags: lua

by default, there is no so file compiled. The default make doesn't support .so
how to modify the Makefile to produce a so file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Linux® From Scratch - Version 8.4 
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/general/lua.html

patch the Makefile by using lua-5.3.5-shared_library-1.patch